# Автоответчик ВКонтакте на нужное сообщения

Tags: php, python, вконтакте

Состою в беседе. Я хочу если какое-то сообщение в беседе будет содержать какое-нибудь слово, то у меня автоматически отправлялось нужное сообщение.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Вам может помочь Python и его библиотека *vk_api*

Вот пример бота:

```py
from random import randint
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


vk_session = VkApi(token="[Ваш токен]")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "[id сообщества]")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        text = event.object['text']

        if 'Какое-то слово' in text:
            random_id = randint(1, 2147483647)
            chat_id = event.chat_id

            message = "[Ваш ответ]"

            vk.messages.send(
                random_id=random_id,
                chat_id=chat_id,
                message=message,
            )
```

*Примечание: В примере используется авторизация по ключу сообщества, так как методы сообщений ограничили и теперь нельзя использовать их напрямую с помощью ключа пользователя. Вам придётся создать сообщество и добавить его в беседу (не забудьте про права на чтение сообщений).*

Comment: Здравствуйте, как её применять? Я хочу что бы автоответчик работал с 9 до 15 часов. Просто сделать скрипт в python и запустить в 9 часов?

Comment: Ошибка в 7 линии с longpoll

Comment: Ошибка в линиях 220, 207, 636...

Comment: @ШамильДавлетханов Я проверил этот код. Python 3.7.3, Windows 10. Всё прекрасно работает... Приведите Вашу ошибку, так будет яснее, что пошло не так. Может Вы использовали неправильный токен? (нужен токен сообщества)